# How to choose any app to launch with the app chooser in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

The following code is essentially copied from [Android document](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#AppChooser):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// Create intent to show chooser
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an app");
// Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

Unfortunately, the app chooser does not show up.  Could anyone point out what is wrong with the above code?

I want to use the chooser to allow the user to select an app, and the app to remember this app, and launch this later in another activity in code,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Intent` does not match any app on the device. My guess is that it is the missing MIME type. Call `setType()` on `intent`, passing in MIME type of the content that you are trying to share.

Your bigger problem is that you are not actually sharing anything (no `EXTRA_TEXT`, nor `EXTRA_STREAM`), and so you may crash whatever activity responds to your `Intent`.

**UPDATE**: Based upon your updated question, you seem to be taking "chooser" too literally. :-) While the chooser allows the user to choose from one of several possible matching activities, the chooser then starts the chosen activity. On newer versions of Android (5.1+, IIRC), there are ways that you can find out that what the chooser chose. But if your objective is *not* to start an activity, but just to have the user choose one... AFAIK, you need to roll your own UI for that, based on `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`. That's basically what a home screen does: find all activities implementing `ACTION_MAIN`/`CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`, then display them for the user to choose from. My [`Launchalot` sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.5/Introspection/Launchalot) demonstrates this process.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  Actually, there is nothing to share.  I just want to select an app via the chooser. It may take too much space to explain why I want to do this (The code is not production code).  Is this possible?

Comment: @Hong: "I just want to select an app via the chooser" -- the chooser does not allow the user to select an app. It allows the user to select an activity. So, if by "app", you really mean "home screen launcher activity", use an `ACTION_MAIN`/`CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` `Intent`, not `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: Thank you again. I think I should tell you exactly what I want, but skip the background for this to save the space.  I want to use the chooser to allow the user to select an app, and the app to remember this app, and launch this later in another activity in code, not instantly.  Am I heading in the wrong direction? I thought the chooser would provide the package name which can be used later to launch the app.

Comment: @Hong: no, the chooser will just turn around and start the chosen activity. Use PackageManager and queryIntentActivities() to get a list of activities matching your Intent, then present your own UI for the user to make a choice. If you search Stack Overflow for Launchalot, that is a sample app of mine for presenting the user with a list of launcher activities.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That is exactly what I want.  I added a sentence to clarify my question.  Could you use the above comment to replace your answer or add to it so that I can accept it?  it may help others with a similar question.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: I followed the code of your Launchlot, but used getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(sAppPackageName) to create an Intent instead of using ResolveInfo to create a ComponentName, then an intent.  It seems to work well.  I do not know if it has any downsides.

Comment: @Hong: If you know the package name, and you are prepared to deal with apps that do not have a launcher activity, your approach should be OK.

Comment: Thank you.  I did not know there are those scenarios. I will add try-catch to deal with them.